# Tic Tac Toe java draw game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

So I did a Tic Tac Toe assignment for my class. I have successfully created a simple Tic Tac Toe program but somehow the method to check for draw sometimes doesn't come out right. If everything is filled but there's no winner, then it's a draw. But if everything else is filled except for row 0 column 1, it will still show "draw" even if that box is still blank. If you don't get what I mean, just try filling out everything but the middle box on the top row but don't win, it will say "draw" even though that last box is not filled. What did I do wrong in my code???? Here's the driver:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class TwoDimensionalArray_Driverr
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    char player = 'o';
    TwoDimensionalArrayy game = new TwoDimensionalArrayy();

    while (game.checkGame() == "PLAY")
    {
      if (player == 'o') player = 'x';
      else player = 'o';
      System.out.println(game);
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Position of Row for player "+ player +" or     press Cancel to exit");
      if (input == null)
        System.exit(0);
      int row = Integer.parseInt(input);

      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Position of Column for player " + player);
      int column = Integer.parseInt(input);

      game.set(row,column,player);
      game.isDraw();
      game.hasWon(row,column,player);
      game.checkGame();
      System.out.println(game.checkGame());
    }
    if (game.checkGame()=="DRAW"){
      System.out.println(game);
      System.out.println("It's a draw.");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println(game);
      System.out.println(player + " has won.");}
  }
}
```

And here is the Object:
    public class TwoDimensionalArrayy
    {
      private String currentState = "GO";
      private char[][] board;
      private static final int ROWS = 3;
      private static final int COLUMNS = 3;

```
  public TwoDimensionalArrayy(){
  board = new char[ROWS][COLUMNS];

  for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++) //always do ROWS first!!!!
    for(int j = 0;j<COLUMNS;j++)
    board[i][j]=' ';
  }

  public void set(int i, int j, char player)
  {
    if(board[i][j] != ' ' )
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position Occupied");
    board[i][j] = player;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    System.out.println("This is the board. 3x3");
    System.out.println("Position start @ row[0]col[0],row[0]col[1],row[0]col[2]");
    String dString= "";
    for (int row = 0; row<ROWS; row++)
    {
      if (COLUMNS>0)
      dString += board[row][0];
      for (int col = 1; col<COLUMNS; col++)
      {
        dString+= "|" + board[row][col];
      } //end 2nd for
      dString += "\n";
    }//end first for
    return dString;
  }

  public String checkGame(){
    if (currentState=="Win"){
      return "END";}
    else if (currentState=="Draw"){
      return "DRAW";}
    else return "PLAY";
  }
  public void hasWon(int i,int j,char player){
    if (board[i][0] == player         // 3-in-the-row
                   && board[i][1] == player
                   && board[i][2] == player
              || board[0][j] == player      // 3-in-the-column
                   && board[1][j] == player
                   && board[2][j] == player
              || i == j            // 3-in-the-diagonal
                   && board[0][0] == player
                   && board[1][1] == player
                   && board[2][2] == player
              || i + j == 2  // 3-in-the-opposite-diagonal
                   && board[0][2] == player
                   && board[1][1] == player
                   && board[2][0] == player)
      currentState = "Win";
  }
  public void isDraw(){
     for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] == ' ') {
               currentState = "Play";
               break;
            }
            else {currentState = "Draw";} // no empty cell, it's a draw}
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void isDraw(){
  for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
      if (board[row][col] == ' ') {
        currentState = "Play";
        break;
      } else {
        currentState = "Draw"; // no empty cell, it's a draw
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The `break` here will escape the inner for loop, but not the outer one. Essentially `isDraw` only considers the last row. You should try using `return` instead.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much! Also if I were to use return, what would I return and how would it work? I'm kinda confused on that part.

Comment: @user3504731 `isDraw` is a `void` method, so it has no return value - a simple `return;` will exit the method.

Comment: Ohhhhh. So if I put return instead of break, it will exit both of the loop? I thought about that too but I thought even if I put return it would still go back through everything. Thank you very much!